# Почему при столкновении персонажа с препятствием происходит отскок?

Tags: unity3d

Имеется блок

[image]

И имеется персонаж

[image]

Движение персонада происходит с помощью изменения позиции Rigidbody2D

Вот весь метод Update персонажа

```
void Start () {
    // Rigidbody2D
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void Update () {
    // Main Camera
    mainView = Camera.main;

    // Mouse Position
    var mousePosition = mainView.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.LookRotation (transform.position - mousePosition, Vector3.forward);

    // Rotation
    transform.rotation = rotate;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z);

    // Reset Rigidbody2D
    body.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    body.angularVelocity = 0;

    // New Position
    var position = new Vector2 (transform.up.x, transform.up.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Mouse Button Down
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        pressed = true;
    }

    // Mouse Button Up
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        pressed = false;
    }

    // Move Player
    if (pressed) {
        body.MovePosition (body.position + position);
    }
}
```

И вот видео самой проблемы
https://youtu.be/9PEV8oIzMxk

Comment: Попробуй MovePosition в FixedUpdate вызывать или настроить физ. материал, чтобы объект не отскакивал при столкновении

Comment: Пробовал FixedUpdate, и пробовал назначать Physics Material 2D, картина не меняется. Если верить форумам, то столкновения нельзя использовать, надо делать нахождения пути, что бы обходить объекты не сталкиваясь с ними. Именно по этой части (столкновения) Unity немножко отстает от аналогов )

Comment: Для таких случаев всегда хаки есть, кидаешь любой Cast(например CircleCast для твоей фигуры подойдет) перед сдвигом вперед, на расстояние, на которое собираешься сдвинутся+5%(погрешность), если есть попадание, то коррелируешь вектор сдвига на расстояние до точки полученной в Cast.

Comment: Да, по сути можно везде тригеров накидать, и тормозить персонажа, но я то думал что в Unity все работает как надо ))

Comment: А зачем везде триггеров накидывать? Cast это не триггер, кидается он чисто из кода.

Comment: Можете не большой пример показать ?